# Instagram scraping amount of comments

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram-api

Does anyone know if there is a proper way to scrape Instagram Profiles? The goal is to automatically collect the amount of comments of the posts of specific users.

Comment: What do you exactly want to scrape ? All comments on all posts of a particular user ? or all comments made by a particular user of different posts of others ?

Comment: The average amount of comments of the last 10 posts of a particular user

Comment: just the latest 10 ?

Comment: yes. Because in most cases posts older than the last 10 are too far in the past and are no longer suitable for a meaningful data analysis of the current account performance. Do you know an automatable way to access the information?

Comment: would be really helpful if you would share it with me!

Answer (score -1):

So you need to hit this API end point with proper browser headers, else you will get a useragent mismatch error

```js
axios.get("https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/feed/user/{username_of_account}/username/?count=12", {
  "headers": {... add all the headers that you get from the browser request},
  "method": "GET"
});
```

To gather your own browser headers, goto the networks tab and open some profile, there you will find a lot of network requests. Just right click on any one of them and copy as Node fetch, you will find the headers there. copy paste those here in this request

in response you will get a json that will have an array named as items.
Iterate over items array and each element will have a property named as `items[i].comment_count`. I mean, ith element of items array.